# How can I access a string, within an object, within an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, class

I'm trying to access the value of a string, within an array of objects. The string is used to create the original object.

I have class Camper, which has constructor Camper(string name);
I then created an array from my Camper class. I want to write an if-statement that catches the 'name' string to compare with a string input by the user.

My errors: 
E0711   expression must have bool type (or be convertible to bool)
C2451   conditional expression of type 'Camper' is illegal

I'm sure the errors are referring to the same issue.

I'm very new to C++ so let me know if you see anything else that doesn't make sense to you, or if this just isn't do-able. Thanks.

```
void addPayment(Camper arr[]) {
    string name;
    cout << "   What is the camper's name?   ";
     cin >> name;
    Camper c = Camper(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); ++i) {

        if (arr[i] == c) {   // Here is where I have the bug
        c.pay();    // What should I use instead of arr[i]?
        }
    }
    cout << "   " << name << " has paid.";
}
```

Comment: `if (arr[i] = c) {` note that `=` is an assignment not a comparison. Use `==` for a comparison

Comment: There are multiple bugs in the shown code. the `=` vs `==` is the least of the problems. For starters, this `sizeof()` doesn't do what you think it does. That's not how `sizeof` works, see your C++ book for a full explanation, including what it means to pass an array as a parameter. Hint: the parameter to this function is not an array. It's a pointer. `sizeof` of a pointer is always the same, whether the underlying array has one element, or one billion elements. The shown code will not work correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it just didn't work with = or == so I left it to ask the question. - fixed

Comment: `void addPayment(Camper arr[]) ` if you can't use a std::vector you must pass the number of items in the array. `sizeof()` can not work.

Comment: You are making a common mistake of writing a bunch of code first, and only then attempt to compile the whole thing and see if it works. Professional programmers don't work this way. They write only a few lines of code, compile, test it to make it sure just what they wrote works correctly, then write the next couple of lines of code, and so on. It'll be faster for you to scrap the whole thing and start from scratch, working in very small steps, and testing what you wrote after each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (arr[i] == c) you should overwrite your '=='in your Camper

```
bool operator==(const Camper &a,const Camper &b) 
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked but i have more issues now haha

Comment: ***i have more issues now*** My advice is to use a debugger. And what I mean by that is use it to step through your code 1 line at a time. Look at the important variables at each step you make until the code behaves differently than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are decayed into pointers in function parameters. The type of your `arr` is `Camper*`. `sizeof(arr)` doesn't return the value you are expecting. You have to provide the number of elements as a separate parameter.